# Remove first and last IP from netaddr result

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a script to print all IPs in CIDR notaion, but I do not want to print first and last IPs as they are not usable.

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
ipc = raw_input('Enter The IP Range ')
n = 0
for ip in IPNetwork(ipc):
    n = n + 1
    print '%s' % ip
print 'Total No of IPs are ' + str(n)
```

This means that if I give 12.110.34.224/27 I should get 30 IPs as result, removing first and last IPs as /27 means 32 IPs.

Comment: This is so trivial. Please invest time to look at what the programming language provides you with. Do a basic tutorial and this question does not need to be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it.

```
for ip in list(IPNetwork(ipc))[1:-1]:
```